# Keep the selected options in the Sidebar when resizing the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

My site has a sidebar (FiltersSideBar in my code) that contains filters. When the browser is expanded to full screen, the sidebar is in open mode on the left. If the screen width becomes less than 600, the sidebar is hidden and a button (ArrowBackIosNewIcon in my code) appears that can open the sidebar (as if overlaying the home page).

The problem with my code is that when the sidebar changes position (opens/closes), its state is not saved - all sidebar elements return to their original state. Although the applied filters continue to work.

That is, if the user selected any filters in the full-screen mode (for example, checked some categories), they were applied. But after that the browser window shrinks, the filters themselves remain applied, but the sidebar is displayed in the default mode (i.e. the checkboxes are empty again).

I would like to make it so that regardless of the size of the page the sidebar retains its appearance.

FiltersSideBar.jsx

```
 export default function FiltersSideBar(props) {
    return (
        <CardContent className={props.className}>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter1 />
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter2 />
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </CardContent>
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? You can use Stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you pass the filters to the sidebar.

But this issue happens because you completely destroy the sidebar to hide which resets its state to default, it would be better to just manipulate the style with `display` and `transition` without destroying the sidebar.

like here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hodgkin-lf7qwt

Another solution is to make the filters state in the parent component of the sidebar and pass props to it.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. Could you help me implement the second option with my code?

Comment: Sure, could you provide a working example on codesandbox?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. Very large code and very many components. I will let you know when I do

Comment: No problem, take your time.

Comment: Here is the link, I shortened my code for demo. I partially solved my problem. I just need to save the state of the filter, here I mean: is it closed or open. For example: if you open the filter at the full width of the browser (by clicking on the down arrow), and then reduce the width of the browser, the filter will close. Is it possible to make it so that the filter does not automatically close?

Comment: The code give errors when load, would you check.

Comment: i am sorry, check now

Comment: Please check.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-clarke-y4kc5n

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. But I also meant that if the user opens the filter (by clicking on the down arrow), then until the user himself closes the filter, the filter cannot change its position, regardless of the screen size.

Just for now, if you open the filter (by clicking the down arrow), select options, and change the screen size, you will have to open the filter again (by clicking the down arrow). I would like until the user closes the filter so that it does not collapse itself

Comment: You are welcome, Done, please check again.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks again! You are an amazing programmer.

Comment: Sure, it's my pleasure